# What is the meaning of "i32 (...)**" in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I was reading Clang++ produced LLVM IR code of following code:

```
class Shape {
  public:
  // pure virtual function providing interface framework.
  virtual int getArea(char* me) = 0;
  void setWidth(int w) {
    width = w;
  }
  
  void setHeight(int h) {
    height = h;
  }
  
  protected:
  int width;
  int height;
};

// Derived classes
class Rectangle: public Shape {
  public:
  int getArea(char * me) {
    return (width * height);
  }
};
```

which produces following LLVM IR :

```
%class.Rectangle = type { %class.Shape }
%class.Shape = type { i32 (...)**, i32, i32 }
```

What is this " i32 (...)** " ? What does it do ?

From the looks of "i32 (...)**", this looks like function pointer but used to bitcast objects.

like so :

```
define linkonce_odr dso_local void @_ZN9RectangleC2Ev(%class.Rectangle* %0) unnamed_addr #5 comdat align 2 {
  %2 = alloca %class.Rectangle*, align 8
  store %class.Rectangle* %0, %class.Rectangle** %2, align 8
  %3 = load %class.Rectangle*, %class.Rectangle** %2, align 8
  %4 = bitcast %class.Rectangle* %3 to %class.Shape*
  call void @_ZN5ShapeC2Ev(%class.Shape* %4) #3
  %5 = bitcast %class.Rectangle* %3 to i32 (...)***
  store i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ({ [3 x i8*] }, { [3 x i8*] }* @_ZTV9Rectangle, i32 0, inrange i32 0, i32 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 (...)*** %5, align 8
  ret void
}
```

Comment: The `i32 (...)*` is a pointer to variadic function that returns `i32`. Here you have double pointer. This probably should be understood as an array of functions, i.e. this looks like vtable implementation for virtual calls. That also explains variadic `(...)` params, cause that vtable covers all possible function signatures. Although I'm not sure why it returns `i32`. I think that `@_ZN9RectangleC2Ev` is a constructor. Is that code setting up appropriate vtable on the instance? I'm not sure, the code is some weird implementation detail.

Comment: @freakish you confused me on so many levels. Change return type of virtual function to anything and its still "i32 (...)**", what i understand from  @_ZN9RectangleC2Ev is that, it creates a shape object and stores it into "i32 (...)***". Pointer is a pointer right. i8* should do the job, but instead it stores Shape object into i32 (...)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's watch simpler code

```
struct A {
  virtual void f1();
  int width;
};

struct B: public A {
  void f1() {};
};

B a;
```

After compilation it is possible to get [this](https://godbolt.org/z/16fjdYcn3):

```
%struct.B = type { %struct.A.base, [4 x i8] }
%struct.A.base = type <{ i32 (...)**, i32 }>

@a = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global %struct.B { %struct.A.base <{ i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ({ [3 x i8*] }, { [3 x i8*] }* @_ZTV1B, i32 0, inrange i32 0, i32 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 0 }>, [4 x i8] zeroinitializer }, align 8
@_ZTV1B = linkonce_odr dso_local unnamed_addr constant { [3 x i8*] } { [3 x i8*] [i8* null, i8* bitcast ({ i8*, i8*, i8* }* @_ZTI1B to i8*), i8* bitcast (void (%struct.B*)* @_ZN1B2f1Ev to i8*)] }, comdat, align 8
```

As it possible to see, `i32 (...)**` is for `_ZTV1B`, which will become `vtable for B` after demangling.

As we see that mystery function is:

```
getelementptr inbounds ({ [3 x i8*] }, { [3 x i8*] }* @_ZTV1B, i32 0, inrange i32 0, i32 2)
```

Which is `_ZN1B2f1Ev` after GEP, which is `B::f1()` after demangling.

I also tried [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/EYoo5M6jh):

```
auto f(B *a) {
    a->f1();
}
```

Generated code is:

```
define dso_local void @_Z1fP1B(%struct.B* %0) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %2 = bitcast %struct.B* %0 to void (%struct.B*)***
  %3 = load void (%struct.B*)**, void (%struct.B*)*** %2, align 8, !tbaa !3
  %4 = load void (%struct.B*)*, void (%struct.B*)** %3, align 8
  tail call void %4(%struct.B* nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(12) %0)
  ret void
}
```

As it possible to see, it simply takes needed function and calls it.

[P.S.](https://reviews.llvm.org/D5916)

> We currently use i32 (...)** as the type of the vptr field in the LLVM
> struct type. LLVM's GlobalOpt prefers any bitcasts to be on the side
> of the data being stored rather than on the pointer being stored to.

Comment: @MusaKalaycı mark as resolved, if possible :)

Comment: i will as soon as i learned how. let me open another question :)